# html5 video not playing in firefox on Apple machinees

Tags: javascript, ios, html, firefox, video

I've added a HTML5 video to a site I'm working on & everything is working fine execept it doesn't play on firefox on Apple machines only, it works well on all other browsers even with firefox on Windows & linux.

One thing which I've done is remove the controls from the video and added an image of a play button for the user to click for to play the video & an image of a close button to close/stop the video.

Any idea what may be causing this, I think it may be a browser specific issue which doesn't allow videos to play without controls, but this is an effect we really want.

**HTML 5**

```
<div id="video-wrapper" style="z-index: 210; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    <div align="center">
        <video id="hp-video-player" preload="auto" poster="/wp-content/uploads/Homepage_arival_preview.jpg" style="display: inline-block;">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="/wp-content/uploads/Homepage_Movie.mp4"><source type="video/webm" src="/wp-content/uploads/Homepage_Movie.webm"><object width="1900" height="1060" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://development.com/wp-content/themes/jupiter/js/flashmediaelement.swf"></object><param name="movie" value="http://development.com/wp-content/themes/jupiter/js/flashmediaelement.swf"><param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=/wp-content/uploads/Homepage_Movie.mp4"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/Homepage_arival_preview.jpg" title="No video playback capabilities"></video>
        <img id="video-close-btn" src="http://development.com/wp-content/themes/jupiter-child/images/x-close-menu.png" style="display: inline;">
        <div align="center"><img id="hp-play-btn" src="http://development.com/wp-content/themes/jupiter-child/images/play_button.png" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var video = jQuery("#hp-video-player").get(0);

jQuery("#hp-play-btn").click(function() {  // Play button Click Actions
    video.play();
    jQuery("#hp-video-player, #video-close-btn").fadeIn(300);
    jQuery(this).fadeOut(500);
    jQuery("#video-wrapper").css({'background-color' : '#000000', 'z-index' : '210'});
}

jQuery("#video-close-btn").click(function(){ // Close button Click Actions
  video.pause();
  jQuery("#hp-video-player, #video-close-btn").fadeOut(500);
  jQuery("#hp-play-btn").fadeIn(300);
  jQuery("#video-wrapper").css({'background-color' : 'transparent', 'z-index' : '65'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

H264/MP4 is not supported on Firefox Desktop on OSX yet.

Sett eh [Supported Formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility) article and/or [the bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=941296) aiming to implement it.

Comment: what about .webm  I've added that format also `<source type="video/webm" src="/wp-content/uploads/Homepage_Movie.webm">` should firefox on OSX not fall back to use webm if it can't use mp4?

Comment: You're right. I missed that (didn't scroll). There are many reasons why the WEBM might not be displayed, such as wrong mime types, wrong encoding, etc. IIRC the WebConsole will give warnings about media types and why certain sources failed to load.

Comment: what do you mean by 'IIRC the WebConsole', do you mean check in firbug?

Comment: "If I remember correctly". And I mean the Web Console of the built-in Firefox developer tools (Tools/Web Developer/Web Console). No idea if Firebug displays warnings as well.